# ls | wc -l inside if statement not working

Tags: shell, qshell

I am new in qshell and would like to ask for assistance.
I am trying to get the file count inside an IFS directory using below qshell command.

```
if(ls <<path>> | wc -l) -gt 0;                    
then echo correct;                                                
fi
```

however im getting this error "token word not expected, expecting token "then".
TIA

Comment: Is the PowerShell tag appropriate?

Comment: @Jack - it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below snippet should work for you

```
if test $(ls <<path>> | wc -l) -gt 0;
then echo correct;
fi
```

test is used to check the condition, and $() executes the command present inside